# Books of combinatorics, with dynamic programming

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, dynamic-programming

Does anybody recommend a good book of combinatorics, especially with a lot of dynamic programming techniques? I'm looking for something really advanced, as I'm just finishing my undergrad in computer science.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's heavy on dynamic programming, but I've heard very good things about Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms by Cameron.

Ordered myself a copy just a few days ago in fact.

Comment: I checked the contents and the index. It seems to be a very good book, but I didn't find the words 'dynamic programming' explicitly... Maybe there is something related to that, or it appears with other names, or with no name at all... Thanks for the recommendation anyway!